# How do I convert an array of characters to a set?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, char, set

How do I solve this error converting an array into a set?

```java
String line = scan.nextLine();
char[] arr = line.toCharArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
HashSet<Character> repeat = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(arr));
System.out.println(repeat);
```

The error is:

```
error: no suitable constructor found for HashSet(List<char[]>)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList(arr)` does not give you a `List<Character>` that you would use as `Collection<Character>` in your call to the `HashSet` constructor.

It gives `List<char[]>`, which would be an incorrect value as the expected `Collection<Character>` type. It's this conflict that's making your compilation fail.

The way to fix it is by creating a `List<Character>` and adding elements to it one by one, or, even simpler, to do that straight with the set itself:

```
Set<Character> repeat = new HashSet<>();
for(char c: arr)
    repeat.add(c);
```

There are many alternative approaches, but it boils down to copying elements from the char array to the set, via a list or not.

Answer (score 0):

@nebneb-5 Try this -

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        //char[] arr = line.toCharArray();
        List<Character> list = line.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Set<Character> repeat = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        System.out.println(repeat);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no point in collecting to a `List<Character>`, just to stream again and collect to a `Set<Character>`. Just collect the first stream to `Set<Character>` directly. Further, there’s no reason to keep the `char[] arr = line.toCharArray();` when you don’t use that array.

Comment: @Holger I am totally agree with your comment, but sometime people are more specific to there code.
else the previous answer provided by ernest_k is perfect one.

Comment: This has nothing to do with being specific. Collecting into a `List` is an entirely obsolete operation here that almost doubles the time needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) method for this porpose:

```java
String line = "abcdeeadfc";

HashSet<Character> repeat = line.codePoints()
        .mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

System.out.println(repeat); // [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How do I add String to a char array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65385536/14838237)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

### Java-9 solution:

```
Set<Character> repeat = line.chars()
                        .mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Check [`String#chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#chars--) and [`IntStream#mapToObj`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) to learn more about them.