# How do I add String to a char array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    char[][] c = {{'a', 'b', 'c'},
                  {'d', 'e', 'f'}};
    show(c);        
}
public static void show (char[][] c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(c[i]);
```

I want a space between each letter. I tried to write + " " after c[i] but then I get this warning: "Must explicitly convert the char[] to a String". How I am supposed to add a string to my array?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now what you are doing wrong is, you are printing each sub-array. I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. But if you want to print each `char` of your 2D char array with space between each letter, then you should use two `for` loops to iterate over the whole 2D array and print each char like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] c = { { 'a', 'b', 'c' }, { 'd', 'e', 'f' } };
    show(c);
}

public static void show(char[][] c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(c[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a b c d e f
```

Edit:

To print each sub-array in a seperate line, simply change the `show` method like this:

```
public static void show(char[][] c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(c[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(); // add a println here
    }
}
```

New output:

```
a b c 
d e f
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I meant, sorry if I was unclear with my question.
Is it possible to get  "a b c" and "d e f" on two different lines?
That's the output I got with my code (without the spaces).

Comment: @Jumpal0t I edited the answer. `System.out.println()` prints the content passed, (here we pass nothing) and then prints a new line.

Answer (score 1):

With Java Streams you can do it:

```
    Arrays.stream(c).map(String::valueOf)
                    .map(i -> i.replace("", " "))
                    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

for the output

```
a b c  d e f
```

or :

```
   Arrays.stream(c).map(String::valueOf)
                   .map(i -> i.replace("", " "))
                   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

for the output:

```
a b c 
d e f
```

For each array of chars in the 2D array of chars we convert to a `String`:

```
map(String::valueOf)
```

then we add a " " between the character of each String:

```
 map(i -> i.replace("", " "))
```

finally we print the result each String:

```
forEach(System.out::println)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) method to iterate over `int` values of the characters of this 2d array and add spaces between them:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] chars = {{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'d', 'e', 'f'}};
    System.out.println(spaceBetween(chars)); // a b c d e f
}
```

```java
public static String spaceBetween(char[][] chars) {
    return Arrays.stream(chars)
            // Stream<char[]> to IntStream
            .flatMapToInt(arr -> String.valueOf(arr).codePoints())
            // codepoints as characters
            // return Stream<Character>
            .mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch)
            // characters as strings
            // return Stream<String>
            .map(String::valueOf)
            // join characters with
            // whitespace delimiters
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Is there any other way to remove all whitespaces in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65382822/14838237)</sup>