# Is there any other way to remove all whitespaces in a string?

Tags: java, string, replace, whitespace

I have a programming homework. It says that I need to reverse the string first, then change it to uppercase and then remove all the whitespaces. I actually did it, but our professor didn't say anything about using `replaceAll()` method. Is there any other way to do it beside `replaceAll()`?

Here is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "the quick brown fox";
    String reverse = "";

    for (int i = line.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse = reverse + line.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(reverse.toUpperCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check each character in turn using `Character.isWhitespace`. Additionally, it is generally better to use a `StringBuilder` when concatenating inside a loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "the quick brown fox";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line.length());

    for (int i = line.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char c = line.charAt(i);
        if(!Character.isWhitespace(c)) sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Khelwood's answer as code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "the quick brown fox";
    String reverse = "";

    for (int i = line.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char currentChar = line.charAt(i);
        if (currentChar != ' ') {
            reverse += currentChar;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(reverse.toUpperCase());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

to strictly follow the professors *description* (and intentions?):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "the quick brown fox";

    String reverse = "";
    for (int i = line.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse = reverse + line.charAt(i);
    }

    String upperCase = reverse.toUpperCase();

    String noSpaces = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < upperCase.length(); i++) {
        char ch = upperCase.charAt(i);
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
            noSpaces = noSpaces + ch;  // or noSpaces += ch;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(noSpaces);
}
```

Note 1: this can all be done with one loop, but that would not match the *description* (or no (user)loop at all?).

<sub>Note 2: the use of `StringBuilder` is not needed anymore (when using an actual Java version (>= 11)) - actually I believe it is more efficient not to use it, the compiler does better job (see `StringConcatFactory`)</sub>

<sub>Note 3: if allowed to use `StringBuilder`, it also has a `reverse` method</sub>

Note 4: be aware (for future) that `replaceAll()` works with regular expression, very powerful, but kind of overkill to just replace a char - `replace()` would be more moderate

Comment: `StringConcatFactory` _explicitly_ states that it's for creating concatenators for _a known number of inputs_; use in a loop doesn't match its description.

Comment: @chrylis *known number of inputs* is the case here, or? the code is just concatenating **two** strings - concatenation of above code would be similar to `noSpaces = $concat2(noSpaces, ch);` (method name is not correct, just as example) ((if you don't believe, check generated code with decompiler))

Comment: @chrylis the loop is not eliminated by using the factory, just the (hidden) use of StringBuilder is eliminated - details: [JEP280](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280)

Comment: The entire point of "use `StringBuilder` in loop" is to avoid creating the new `String` object on every loop iteration. "We're creating all those new objects _slightly faster_" doesn't obviate that.

Comment: @chrylis not 100% correct, the point also was to avoid creating a new SrtingBuilder (and some arrays) each iteration. Not sure how that last comment relates to your first comment, or to my comments... somehow I don't think OP should yet learn about (micro-)optimization It seams more like the teacher wants to teach basics like `for` loop, `if` statement and that...

Comment: *For expressions like `a + ":" + b`*, not for loop unrolling.

Comment: @chr sorry, my English is too bad, no idea what you are trying to write now, and it looks like you do not understand (or read) what I wrote - no point in going on with that,

Answer (score 1):

Even without using `replaceAll()` it’s still a one-liner:

```java
String reverse =
        new StringBuilder(line)
                .reverse()
                .toString()
                .toUpperCase()
                .replace(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

### [`Character#isWhitespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char))

Initialize a `StringBuilder` object and iterate through each character of the uppercased string. While iterating, use `Character#isWhitespace` to check if the character is a whitespace character. If not, append the character to the `StringBuilder` object. After the loop is finished, the `StringBuilder` object will have all characters except the whitespace characters.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "the quick brown fox";
        String reverse = "";

        for (int i = line.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reverse = reverse + line.charAt(i);
        }
        String upperCased = reverse.toUpperCase();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < upperCased.length(); i++) {
            char ch = upperCased.charAt(i);
            if (!Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The given string: " + line);
        System.out.println("The reverse of the given string: " + reverse);
        System.out.println("The reverse of the given string in UPPER case: " + upperCased);
        System.out.println("After removing all space from the reverse of the given string in UPPER case: " + sb);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The given string: the quick brown fox
The reverse of the given string: xof nworb kciuq eht
The reverse of the given string in UPPER case: XOF NWORB KCIUQ EHT
After removing all space from the reverse of the given string in UPPER case: XOFNWORBKCIUQEHT
```

**Note:**

1. If you want to convert `sb` to a `String`, use `sb.toString()`.
2. You can use `String` instead of `StringBuilder` but I recommend you use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` for such a case because repeated string concatenation in a loop creates additional as many instances of `String`  as the number of concatenation. Check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817951/string-concatenation-in-java-when-to-use-stringbuilder-and-concat) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways.  The first uses a standard loop.

```
String line = "the quick brown fox";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = line.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    char ch;
    if ((ch = line.charAt(i)) != ' ') {
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
    }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Prints

```
XOFNWORBKCIUQEHT
```

The second makes use of `StringBuilder` and `replaceAll`.  And regardless, you should ask your professor since nothing was overtly forbidden.

```
String str = new StringBuilder("the quick brown fox")
        .reverse().toString().replaceAll("\\s+", "").toUpperCase();

System.out.println(str);
```

Also prints

```
XOFNWORBKCIUQEHT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) method to iterate over `int` values of the characters of this string, to reverse their order, change to uppercase and remove whitespaces:

```java
String line = "the quick brown fox";

String reverse = line
        // return IntStream
        .codePoints()
        // return Stream<Character>
        .mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch)
        // reverse the order
        // of characters once
        .sorted((ch1, ch2) -> -1)
        // change to uppercase
        .map(Character::toUpperCase)
        // remove whitespaces
        .filter(ch -> !Character.isWhitespace(ch))
        // return Stream<String>
        .map(String::valueOf)
        // join strings with
        // characters back
        // to a single string
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(reverse); // XOFNWORBKCIUQEHT
```

---

<sup>See also: [Is there a way to reverse specific arrays in a multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65383974/14838237)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to store the reversed line, you can also just iterate it backwards and print the character immediately.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "the quick brown fox";
    for (char c : line.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) over character indices in reverse order, convert them to uppercase and remove spaces as follows:

```java
String str = "the quick brown fox";
String reverse = IntStream
        // iterate over characters in reverse order
        .iterate(str.length() - 1, i -> i >= 0, i -> i - 1)
        // take a character by its index
        .mapToObj(str::charAt)
        // filter only letters
        .filter(Character::isLetter)
        // character to uppercase
        .map(Character::toUpperCase)
        // Stream<String>
        .map(String::valueOf)
        // concatenate into one line
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

// output
System.out.println(reverse); // XOFNWORBKCIUQEHT
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence of actions does not matter, then you can first change this string to uppercase, then *stream* over the character codepoins and filter out whitespaces, and then concatenate back the remaining characters in reverse order:

```java
String line = "the quick brown fox";
String reverse = line
        // upper case String
        .toUpperCase()
        // IntStream over the character code points
        .codePoints()
        // filter out the space characters
        .filter(ch -> !Character.isSpaceChar(ch))
        // Stream<String>
        .mapToObj(Character::toString)
        // concatenate characters in reverse order
        .reduce((a, b) -> b + a)
        .orElse(null);

System.out.println(reverse); // XOFNWORBKCIUQEHT
```